# Showing that there exists a bijection from $\{0,1\}^X$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory

This is possibly a duplicate, but I was unable to find a post that would answer this question. If you do find it, please put it in comments and I will delete my post.

Suppose you have a $\{0,1\}^X$ which is the set of mappings from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$, show that there exists a bijection from $\{0,1\}^X$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

I know that $X$ cannot be finite, but to understand better the situation, I first assumed $X$ to be finite. Then by using combinatorics notions, I could see that $\{0,1\}^X$ most likely would have $2^{|X|}$ elements, just like $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Yet in case $X$ is infinite(and it always is), $2$ to the power of infinity doesn't make much sense. Could you show me how to show that there exists a bijection? Or is there a theorem for that?

Comment: **Hint:**  Let $A\subseteq X$.  Define $f_A(x)$ based on whether or not $x\in A$.

Comment: Your idea to try the finite case is an excellent one.  Let $X=\{4,5,6}$, so $\{0,1\}^X$ and $\mathcal P(X)$ each have $8$ elements.  Can you find a simple bijection between them?  Can you find a bijection that easily extends to any finite size $X$?  If you find the one I am thinking of, it also extends easily to infinite $X$.  In set theory $2^{|X|}$ does make sense for infinite $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $J:\mathcal{P}(X)\to \{0,1\}^X$ as $J(A)= \chi_A,$ where

$$\chi_A(x)=1, \;x\in A,\;\chi_A(x)=0,\;x\notin A.$$ It is easy to see that $J$ is a bijection.

Comment: I‘m struggling with the idea, that for $J$ to be surjective it needs to hit every element in $\{0,1\}^X$. But how do I know that this $\chi_A(x)$ is actually every element? Can’t there be one that we have forgotten when we simply define $J(A)=\chi_A$?

Comment: @philmcole  Note that any element in $\Psi \in \{0,1\}^X$ is a $\chi_A$ for $$A=\{x\in X: \Psi(x)=1\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$, then let define $\chi_A$ be the caracteristic function of $A$, that is:
$$\forall x\in X,\chi_A(x)=1\iff x\in A\textrm{ and }\chi_A(x)=0\iff x\not\in A.$$
Then, $A\mapsto\chi_A$ is the desired bijection. Can you find its inverse?

Answer (score 1):

For a subset $S\subseteq X$, and for any element $x\in X$, either $x\in S$ or $x\notin S$, which is a binary structure, i.e., a subset $S$ determines a map $f_S: X\rightarrow \{0,1\}^{X}$, which is defined by $f_S(x)=0$ if $x\notin S$ and $f_S(x)=1$ if $x\in S$. This gives a bijection between subsets of X and maps from $X$ to $\{0,1\}^X$.